# Create folders with same names that files and move these files into the new folders

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, recursion

I am trying to create folders with the same name as a number of files in a central folder AND move the files in the folders with the same basename.

```
├── din_UWBM.trimmed_1P.fastq.gz
├── din_UWBM.trimmed_2P.fastq.gz
├── par_UWBM.trimmed_1P.fastq.gz
├── par_UWBM.trimmed_2P.fastq.gz
```

The results will be something like this:

```
├── din_UWBM
│   ├── din_UWBM.trimmed_1P.fastq.gz
│   └── din_UWBM.trimmed_2P.fastq.gz
├── par_UWBM
│   ├── par_UWBM.trimmed_1P.fastq.gz
│   └── par_UWBM.trimmed_2P.fastq.gz
```

I try this script:

```
for file in *_1P.fastq.gz; do
    dir=$(basename -s .trimmed_1P.fastq.gz $file)
    read2=$(find . -name "*.trimmed_2P.fastq.gz");
    mv $file $read2 $dir
done
```

But this only move the *_1P* files, and not the *_2P* (or move to the first folder).

Does someone have any idea of how to resolve this?? I would do it manually but are more of 400 pairs of files!

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the provided filenames, following code will work:

```
for f in *.fastq.gz; do
    d=${f%%.*}          # remove everything after the leftmost dot
    mkdir -p "$d"       # -p option suppress error if the directory already exists
    mv -- "$f" "$d"
done
```